# How to use an alternative pom.xml in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, maven

I am building a production level project and I have 2 pom.xml files,one is `pom.xml` and another is `pom.api.xml`.I have different dependencies installed in both the files.Now even after building the `pom.api.xml` file,I am not able to use the dependencies I installed in it.I am only able to use the dependencies installed in `pom.xml`. How could I use the dependencies in `pom.api.xml` in all the project files like controllers,services etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain more in detail why you need two different pom's...it sounds there is a lack of understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 9 modularity to address it.
Use a root pom to include other poms and their dependencies.
Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity